# How to make a half moon chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get a script for this half moon chart template I saw in the article https://doi.org/10.3390/plants12071451 using ggplot2.

[image]

Comment: Might be of some interest: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/5028

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely pretty hacky, but here’s an approach using `ggplot2::coord_polar()`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(13)

# example data
dat <- tibble(
  id = 1:20,
  `Grain (%)` = runif(20, .525, .625),
  `Straw (%)` = 1 - `Grain (%)`
)

# parameters for y axis and gridlines
panel <- expand_grid(
  x.lab = c(-.25, 21.25), 
  x.grid = c(0, 21),
  y = seq(0, .7, by = .1)
)

dat %>%
  mutate(id = reorder(id, `Grain (%)`, decreasing = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!id, names_to = "type", values_to = "pct") %>%
  ggplot(aes(id, pct)) +
  geom_line(
    data = panel,
    aes(x.grid, y, group = y),
    linewidth = .1,
    color = "gray70"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = panel,
    aes(x.lab, y, label = percent(y)),
    size = 8 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id), color = "gray50") +
  geom_point(aes(color = type), size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(12, 12))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, .7), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_polar(start = pi) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(linewidth = .1, color = "gray70"),
    legend.position = c(.5, .45),
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks fun :D

Data (taking reference from @zephryl's answer):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

n <- 20
set.seed(13)
dat <- tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:n,
  Grain = runif(n, .525, .625),
  Straw = 1 - Grain
) %>%
  arrange(Straw) %>%
  mutate(id = forcats::fct_inorder(as.character(id))) %>%
  mutate(grp = rep(letters, each = 4)[seq_len(n)])
```

Code for a solution in cartesian coordinates:

```
library(ggforce)

angles <- seq_len(n)/(n+1) * pi

dat %>%
  arrange(desc(id)) %>%
  mutate(id.pos = max(c(Grain, Straw)) * 1.2,
         grp.pos = Grain * 1.05,
         angle = angles,
         spoke.radius = Grain - Straw) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(Grain, Straw, id.pos, grp.pos)) %>%
  mutate(x = value * cos(angle), y = value * sin(angle),
         label = case_when(name == "id.pos" ~ as.character(id),
                           name == "grp.pos" ~ grp,
                           TRUE ~ ""),
         spoke.radius = ifelse(name == "Straw", spoke.radius, 0)) %>%
  select(-c(id, grp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  
  # background
  geom_arc(data = data.frame(r = seq(0.1, 0.7, by = 0.1), start = -pi/2, end = pi/2),
           aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = r, start = start, end = end),
           inherit.aes = FALSE, color = "grey") +
  geom_spoke(data = . %>% filter(name == "id.pos"),
             aes(x = 0, y = 0, angle = angle, radius = 0.7),
             color = "grey") +
  annotate("segment", x = -0.7, xend = 0.7, y = 0, yend = 0, color = "black") +
  annotate("segment", x = seq(-0.7, 0.7, 0.1), xend = seq(-0.7, 0.7, 0.1), 
           y = 0, yend = -0.01, color = "black") +
  
  # plot
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle, radius = spoke.radius)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(name %in% c("Grain", "Straw")),
             aes(color = name), size = 4) +
  # labels
  geom_text(aes(label = label, fontface = ifelse(name == "grp.pos", "bold", "plain"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.7, 0.7, 0.1),
                     labels = function(x) scales::percent_format()(abs(x))) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"))
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `plotly::plot_ly(type = 'barpolar')` like this:

```
library(plotly)

p <- 
  plot_ly(
    type = 'barpolar',
    r = c(54.7, 32.6, 8.4, 10.4, 30.6),
    theta = c(0, 40, 80, 120, 160)
  ) %>%
  layout(
    polar = list(
      radialaxis = list(
        visible = TRUE,
        range = c(0, 60)
      ),
      sector = c(0, 180)
    )
  )
p
```

[image]